# Error in retrieving Postgresql DB information with Coturn

Tags: postgresql, webrtc, ubuntu-18.04, postgresql-11, coturn

In order to understand Coturn, and how to use it with Postgresql-11,
I created the postgresql-11 dabatase using /usr/local/share/turnserver/schema.sql  :

```
CREATE TABLE turnusers_lt (
    realm varchar(127) default '',
    name varchar(512),
    hmackey char(128),
    PRIMARY KEY (realm,name)
);

CREATE TABLE turn_secret (
        realm varchar(127) default '',
        value varchar(256),
        primary key (realm,value)
);

CREATE TABLE allowed_peer_ip (
        realm varchar(127) default '',
        ip_range varchar(256),
        primary key (realm,ip_range)
);

CREATE TABLE denied_peer_ip (
        realm varchar(127) default '',
        ip_range varchar(256),
        primary key (realm,ip_range)
);

CREATE TABLE turn_origin_to_realm (
        origin varchar(127),
        realm varchar(127),
        primary key (origin)
);

CREATE TABLE turn_realm_option (
        realm varchar(127) default '',
        opt varchar(32),
        value varchar(128),
        primary key (realm,opt)
);

CREATE TABLE oauth_key (
        kid varchar(128),
        ikm_key varchar(256),
        timestamp bigint default 0,
        lifetime integer default 0,
        as_rs_alg varchar(64) default '',
        realm varchar(127),
        primary key (kid)
);
```

But when trying to execute secure_relay_with_db_psql.sh :

```
(base) marco@marco-U36SG:~/turnserver-4.5.0.8/examples/scripts/longtermsecuredb$ 
./secure_relay_with_db_psql.sh 
0: WARNING: Cannot find config file: turnserver.conf. Default and command-line settings will be 
used.
0: Listener address to use: 127.0.0.1
0: Listener address to use: ::1
0: Relay address to use: 127.0.0.1
0: Relay address to use: ::1
0: 3000000 bytes per second allowed per session
0: WARNING: Cannot find config file: turnserver.conf. Default and command-line settings will
   be used.
0: RFC 3489/5389/5766/5780/6062/6156 STUN/TURN Server
Version Coturn-4.5.0.8 'dan Eider'
0: Max number of open files/sockets allowed for this process: 4096
0: Due to the open files/sockets limitation,
max supported number of TURN Sessions possible is: 2000 (approximately)
0: ==== Show him the instruments, Practical Frost: ====

0: TLS supported
0: DTLS supported
0: DTLS 1.2 supported
0: TURN/STUN ALPN supported
0: Third-party authorization (oAuth) supported
0: GCM (AEAD) supported
0: OpenSSL compile-time version: OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018 (0x1010100f)
0: SQLite is not supported
0: Redis supported
0: PostgreSQL supported
0: MySQL supported
0: MongoDB is not supported
0: 
0: Default Net Engine version: 3 (UDP thread per CPU core)

=====================================================

0: Domain name: 
0: Default realm: north.gov
0: oAuth server name: blackdow.carleon.gov
0: WARNING: cannot find certificate file: turn_server_cert.pem (1)
0: WARNING: cannot start TLS and DTLS listeners because certificate file is not set properly
0: WARNING: cannot find private key file: turn_server_pkey.pem (1)
0: WARNING: cannot start TLS and DTLS listeners because private key file is not set properly
Cannot create pid file: /var/run/turnserver.pid: Permission denied
0: Cannot create pid file: /var/run/turnserver.pid
0: pid file created: /var/tmp/turnserver.pid
0: IO method (main listener thread): epoll (with changelist)
0: Wait for relay ports initialization...
0:   relay 127.0.0.1 initialization...
0:   relay 127.0.0.1 initialization done
0:   relay ::1 initialization...
0:   relay ::1 initialization done
0: Relay ports initialization done
0: IO method (general relay thread): epoll (with changelist)
0: turn server id=0 created
0: IPv4. SCTP listener opened on : 127.0.0.1:3478
0: IPv4. TCP listener opened on : 127.0.0.1:3478
0: IPv4. SCTP listener opened on : 127.0.0.1:3479
0: IPv4. TCP listener opened on : 127.0.0.1:3479
0: IPv6. SCTP listener opened on : ::1:3478
0: IPv6. TCP listener opened on : ::1:3478
0: IPv6. SCTP listener opened on : ::1:3479
0: IPv6. TCP listener opened on : ::1:3479
0: IO method (general relay thread): epoll (with changelist)
0: turn server id=1 created
0: IPv6. TCP listener opened on : ::1:3479
0: IPv6. UDP listener opened on: ::1:3479
0: Total General servers: 3
0: IO method (auth thread): epoll (with changelist)
0: IO method (auth thread): epoll (with changelist)
0: IO method (admin thread): epoll (with changelist)
0: IPv4. CLI listener opened on : 127.0.0.1:5766
0: PostgreSQL DB connection success: host=localhost dbname=coturn user=turn password=turn 
connect_timeout=30
0: ERROR: Error retrieving PostgreSQL DB information: ERROR:  permission denied for table 
allowed_peer_ip
```

But these are the tables of coturndb :

```
coturn=# \dt
                List of relations
     Schema |         Name         | Type  |  Owner   
    --------+----------------------+-------+----------
     public | admin_user           | table | postgres
     public | allowed_peer_ip      | table | postgres
     public | denied_peer_ip       | table | postgres
     public | oauth_key            | table | postgres
     public | turn_origin_to_realm | table | postgres
     public | turn_realm_option    | table | postgres
     public | turn_secret          | table | postgres
     public | turnusers_lt         | table | postgres
(8 rows)

coturn=# \d allowed_peer_ip
                          Table "public.allowed_peer_ip"
  Column  |          Type          | Collation | Nullable |        Default        
----------+------------------------+-----------+----------+-----------------------
 realm    | character varying(127) |           | not null | ''::character varying
 ip_range | character varying(256) |           | not null | 
Indexes:
    "allowed_peer_ip_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (realm, ip_range)

coturn=# \d denied_peer_ip
                          Table "public.denied_peer_ip"
  Column  |          Type          | Collation | Nullable |        Default        
----------+------------------------+-----------+----------+-----------------------
 realm    | character varying(127) |           | not null | ''::character varying
 ip_range | character varying(256) |           | not null | 
Indexes:
    "denied_peer_ip_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (realm, ip_range)

coturn=# \d turn_secret
                           Table "public.turn_secret"
 Column |          Type          | Collation | Nullable |        Default        
--------+------------------------+-----------+----------+-----------------------
 realm  | character varying(127) |           | not null | ''::character varying
 value  | character varying(256) |           | not null | 
Indexes:
    "turn_secret_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (realm, value)
```

Why it says "probably, the tables 'allowed_peer_ip' and/or 'denied_peer_ip' have to be upgraded to include the realm column" ?
Why it says "permission denied" for table turn_secret and for table allowed_peer_ip?
How to solve the problem?

Marco

Answer (score 1):

I feel ashamed for such silly mistake...

I modified the ownership of the database's tables:

```
coturn=# \dt
               List of relations
 Schema |         Name         | Type  | Owner
--------+----------------------+-------+-------
 public | admin_user           | table | turn
 public | allowed_peer_ip      | table | turn
 public | denied_peer_ip       | table | turn
 public | oauth_key            | table | turn
 public | turn_origin_to_realm | table | turn
 public | turn_realm_option    | table | turn
 public | turn_secret          | table | turn
 public | turnusers_lt         | table | turn
(8 rows)
```

And now it works...:

```
./secure_relay_with_db_psql.sh

1: IPv4. CLI listener opened on : 127.0.0.1:5766
1: PostgreSQL DB connection success: host=localhost dbname=coturn user=turn 
password=turn connect_timeout=30
```